# Serial Comm in Debian Auto Timeout

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, debian, posix

I'm using 3.1 Sarge, kernel 2.4.26 on a TS-7400 board running ARM 9 architecture. 
I am using the POSIX library terminos and fcntl.

I am writing a program to communicate between 2 embedded devices over serial. The program uses the POSIX time out flag VTIME and works successfully Ubuntu 10.1 but it does not time out on the board. I need the program to try resending a command if there is no response after a certain time. I know the board is transmitting OK the first time but then the program locks up waiting for a response. I am running the serial in delay mode so it will wait in read() until at least 1 byte is received or .1 secs have passed as defined by VTIME.

What is the problem or if VTIME simply does not work in this kernel what is another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigate the select() system call.  This will let you execute a read when there is something to actually read, instead of waiting for .1 seconds, hoping something will show up.  If this is supposed to be a straight port of your code then this may not be and appropriate thing to do.

It is an alternative....